# How to redirect to an activity after a facebook login in a fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, authentication

I've follow this guide ( [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2)) with succes and I can login with my app. Now what is does, it gives you a login and as soon as you are logged in you can log out, but of course I have put some activities in between. I've tried to so so with Intent, but without a lot of succes. Can someone please help me? this is my code of the activity and the fragment with the login and I need to go to the secondActivity page after I've successfully logged in.

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private MainFragment mainFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
}
```

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

Mainfragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private final List<String> permissions;

public MainFragment() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status");
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};


}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after logging in successfully the API would return to your application and call onActivityResult with a specific resultCode that I guess is [RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) ,so I think this would help:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, i edited it a little bit and it works now

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == result_OK) {
            Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(MainFragment.this.getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
        }

    }